# Live server extension is not installing in VS Code

Tags: vscode-extensions

**I am new to Node.js and VISUAL STUDIO CODE Editor.**
When trying to install "Live server extension" in visual studio code I am getting Error message.
**Error Message:**
Error while installing 'Live Server' extension. Please check the log for more details.
Try Downloading manually... when I clicked on log then I get such error message.
"**[error]**

end of central directory record signature not found: CorruptZip: end of central directory record signature not found
at $t.download (c:\Users\PROGRAMMER_RIXWAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:141)at process.processTicksAndRejections(node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)at async ee.y (c:\Users\PROGRAMMER_RIXWAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:20021)
at async ee.h (c:\Users\PROGRAMMER_RIXWAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:18112)"

---